# Proof by induction for positive real numbers

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I am trying to, for self-study, prove the following fact for positive real numbers.

> Let $a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_n \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be positive real numbers.
> Then, one of the following two inequalities holds:
> $$
>     \frac{a_1}{b_1} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{b_n} \geq n 
>     \hspace{10pt} \mathrm{or} \hspace{10pt} 
>     \frac{b_1}{a_1} + \cdots + \frac{b_n}{a_n} \geq n.
>   $$

Here is my attempt at a solution.

> Let's proceed by induction on $n$. Let $n = 1$. Then we either have $a_1 \geq b_1$ or $a_1 \leq b_1$. If $a_1 \geq b_1$, then $\frac{a_1}{b_1} \geq 1$. If $a_1 \leq b_1$, then $\frac{b_1}{a_1} \geq 1$.
>
> Suppose the inequality holds for $n$. We will show it for $n + 1$. Let $a_1, \ldots, a_{n}, a_{n+1}, b_1, \ldots, b_n, b_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be positive. By the induction hypothesis, we either have
> $$
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n  \hspace{10pt} \mathrm{or} \hspace{10pt} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{a_i} \geq n.
> $$
> Suppose first that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n$. If $a_{n+1} \geq b_{n+1}$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \geq 1$, and so
> $$
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n + 1.
> $$
> If $a_i \leq b_i$, then $0 < \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq 1$, so.
> $$
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{a_i}{b_i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b_i} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} > n,
> $$
> so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n+1$. By swapping labels, the exact same argument shows that if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{a_i} \geq n$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{b_i}{a_i} \geq n + 1$.

How does this proof look?

Comment: Alternative approach:

It is well-known, and not difficult to prove, that

$$ \frac{a_i}{b_i}+\frac{b_i}{a_i}\geq 2\quad\forall\ i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$$

This implies 

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}+\frac{b_i}{a_i}\geq 2n.$$

$$\implies\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{b_i}{a_i}\geq 2n.\qquad (1)$$

If both $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}<n\ $ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}<n,\ $ then $\ (1)\ $ is false. It follows that either $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n\ $ or $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b_i}\geq n.$

Comment: I had trouble following your analysis, which I (therefore) think is invalid.  In particular, in your inductive step, what happens when $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq n ~~\text{and} ~~\color{red}{a_{n+1} < b_{n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is currently not correct. In the case where
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{b_i}\ge n\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}<1$$
you say that then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{a_i}{b_i}\ge n+1,$$
but this is not necessarily true. To give a concrete example (and build intuition), you can consider $a_1=3,b_1=2,a_2=1,b_2=2$.

Comment: isn't there something (inequality) missing for the ratio a(n+1)/b(n+1) ?

Comment: Of course, thank I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>-1$ (so dividing by $1+x$ do not swap inequality) then consider this result:

$$1-x^2\le 1\implies 1-x\le \frac 1{1+x}$$

From there let's define $\dfrac{a_i}{b_i}=1+u_i\quad$ and $\quad U=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n u_i$

Note that $a_i,b_i>0\implies u_i>-1$

We have $\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1+u_i)=n+U\\
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{a_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac 1{1+u_i}\ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1-u_i) = n-U
\end{cases}$

Therefore it is obvious that depending on the sign of $U$, one of these two expressions is greater than $n$.

---

Here is an alternate proof, for $x>0$ we have $(x-1)^2\ge 0\implies x+\frac 1x\ge 2$

Therefore $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{a_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \Big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}+\frac{b_i}{a_i}\Big)\ge\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2=2n$

So one of the two sums is greater than $n$, indeed if $S_1+S_2\ge 2n$ then

- either $S_1\ge n$
- or $S_1\le n\implies -S_1\ge -n\implies S_2\ge 2n-S_1\ge 2n-n\ge n$